# Objects not rotating or scaling in viewport

Tags: objects, transforms

My issue is that I have a blender file in which cameras and lamps do not move when I attempt to rotate them using the mouse. If I select the objects (in object mode), press <kbd>R</kbd>, and move the mouse in the viewport, the lamps and cameras don't respond; they remain in the same orientation as when I started, no matter how vigorously I try to move the mouse. The values in the information bar show that the mouse is communicating. If, however, I manually enter a new value for the amount of rotation in the properties shelf of the viewport, the camera moves to the new orientation.

On a new default Blender scene, the cameras and lamps do respond to commands to rotate and scale using the mouse. I've compared all of the settings I can think of, and don't see anything obvious that corrects the problem.

[~.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zb07ig4vjdq2t8/lamprotation.blend?dl=0) is available.

Comment: Can you share the blend file? You might have locked a transform axis or something similar.

Comment: Maybe, but I checked all the transform locks I could think of.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Untick *Maniplulate center points* in the header. This transforms center points only and allows you to manipulate object locations while having the objects themselves stay in their existing orientation.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Blender 2.8 it is actually on the top middle of the viewport:

[image]

In

> Pivot Point.
>
> Pivot center for rotation/scaling: Median Point
>
> Pivot around the median point of selected objects

make sure the `only origins` option is deselected:

> Only Origins
>
> Manipulate Origins (Object, pose and weight paint. mode only)

Comment: In 2.90.1 I found the setting to be under the top right Options menu. It reads 
Transform Affect only
X Origins
X Locations
X Parents
I had to untick all of them to get rotation and scaling to work. This discussion gave me a clue as to where to look: https://developer.blender.org/T69003