# My lights move but don't rotate

Tags: lighting

I make a new scene, create a light, any light press R and it doesn't rotate the beam of light at all. I am sure I have rotated lights before. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is [*Manipulate Object Origins*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15263/599) enabled by any chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects not rotating or scaling in viewport](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/objects-not-rotating-or-scaling-in-viewport)

Answer (score 3):

see if you have 'Manipulate Center Points' checked on. If so, turn it off.
[image]

ps:Point Lights don't rotate.

Comment: I switched it on and off still doesnt rotate. the spotlight does but the sun doesn't

Comment: You can restore factory settings (File>Load Factory Settings). If you have a customized startup and don't want to loose it, can you post your configuration files? (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

Comment: does the sun just not rotate?

Comment: The only visual clue that the sun is rotating is a thin dotted line showing the direction.