# Rotating / positioning lighting

Tags: lighting

[image: how do I rotate this lamp?]Total noob here,

I am searching the whole internet looking for how to rotate a lamp.

I see several youtube videos showing it being done and saying "rotate lamp ..." How do you rotate a lamp? I can't leave Object mode with the lamp highlighted. I understand that you don't rotate Point lights as they are omnidirectional. You should be able to rotate almost any other lamp. "R" doesn't activate rotation. What am I doing wrong? It seems like it must be the easiest thing to do because nobody has had to answer it before!

Comment: yes the other lamps should rotate except if you've locked its Transform parameters in the N panel?

Comment: Please include a Blender screen capture of your situation in this question and all future questions.  You wrote ... [total noob] ... thus others may be able to read your screen capture and see something you are not seeing.

Comment: General light tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTMORaEygRE

Comment: Lamp like camera object doesn't have any interaction mode other than Object mode and it's the one where you should rotate it. Rotation is often done with shortcut R. If it doesn't work then you changed some settings of the lamp like suggested above and as above a screenshot would be helpful

Comment: Mr Zak, I haven't done anything to it. In fact, I deleted it and added a new one, the only thing I did was put it in the approximate position for the set. When I press "R" I get a second dotted line that follows my cursor but it doesn't change the direction of the lamp. There has got to be something obvious that I am overlooking.

Comment: Disable *Manipulate Center Points* in the 3d viewport header (or Alt + coma). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/objects-not-rotating-or-scaling-in-viewport

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I assume you've figured it out by now, but in Object Mode: look to the bottom left of the screen, you should see a dark grey box, if it says: "Global" click it and select the option that says: "Normal" I just had the same issue as you, but I figured it out. it SHOULD work now.

through looking at your picture, I see that it does say Global.