# Want to render animation nodes text animation on sheepit

Tags: rendering, animation-nodes, sheepit

I have a blender animation where I have used the trim text feature of the animation nodes add-on of blender. However, when I upload it to the render farm, those parts don't render out. I've been told, on blender stack exchange, that it's because the render farm does not have the animation nodes add-on installed. I would however appreciate it if someone suggested a workaround to this.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you. But the solution on that page doesn't seem to be working for me. Could you possibly explain what's being done there with all those nodes?

Comment: Glad I could help. First, did you take a look at the documentation for the nodes used in there? Documentation might make things clearer for you. Let me know if you are still having trouble.

Comment: I went through the documentation and was able to recreate it for my text animation. However, I still do not understand how doing this enables us to "keep the animation but remove the node tree". Do we have to manually add keyframes after doing such a node setup?

Comment: In the overview panel, there is an operator called *Bake To Keyframes*, this will create the keyframes automatically.

Comment: I've run into a problem. If we use the separate text object and convert the text to mesh, I'm not able to reduce the size of the entire mesh(converted from text). If I hit 'S' and scale it down the letters just come closer together. How to resolve this?

Comment: You probably encountered the famous [*"Only Origins"* problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/objects-not-rotating-or-scaling-in-viewport).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's it. But now this weird thing's happening. In my current blend file, ticking and un-ticking the manipulate center points button does nothing to my text. However, in a new blend file, it's working the way it's mean to. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here.